# Is there a way to read hardhat config inside a script at runtime and console.log certain attributes?

Tags: hardhat, rpc, configuration

I want to add some nice output in my hardhat scripts for showing what my configurations are during a test run. I run the script locally while changing configuration variables and I want the console output to reflect those config changes so that I can more easily track things.

For example, here is my hardhat.config.js:

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config();

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.ALCHEMY_URL,
      // url: process.env.INFURA_URL,
      // url: process.env.QUICKNODE_URL,
      // url: process.env.MORALIS_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.PK]
    }  
  }
};
```

And here is my workflow:

1. run the script with existing settings

```bash
thatguyintech@albert eth-call-analysis % npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js
rpc url: localhost
GasLimits contract deployed to: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
```

2. change the `url` config and re-run

```bash
thatguyintech@albert eth-call-analysis % npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network rinkeby
rpc url:  https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/<my api key>
GasLimits contract deployed to: 0xeb8aeddb118b8141ea4e0e0e0d7e7ee685f214ac
```

In order to get the above output, my `sample-script.js` looks like this:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  console.log("rpc url: ", process.env.ALCHEMY_URL) // I have to manually change this on each run.

  // We get the contract to deploy
  const GasLimits = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("GasLimits");
  const gasLimits = await GasLimits.deploy();

  await gasLimits.deployed();

  console.log("GasLimits contract deployed to:", gasLimits.address);
}
```

**Is there a way to read the hardhat.config.js values at runtime so that I don't have to rely on dotenv and change my script manually on each run?**

Specifically, is there a way to rewrite `console.log("rpc url: ", process.env.ALCHEMY_URL)` into something that can automatically update based on how I've set my `hardhat.config.js`? Maybe something like this: `console.log("rpc url: ", hre.config.networks.url)`?

---

Update: I do see in the [hardhat runtime environment docs](https://hardhat.org/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment.html) that there is an `hre.config` object I can use. **However, I don't want to know about the original configuration, I want to know the network that is currently be used at runtime at the time that my script is invoked.** Any tips for that?

Comment: You have access to the HRE in every Hardhat script or task. [Read the docs](https://hardhat.org/advanced/hardhat-runtime-environment.html).

Comment: I saw those docs! I added an update at the end of the question to clarify. I want to know at runtime in my script which network is being run.

Comment: That's not possible as of right now. [See this conversation](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/pull/1542).

Comment: Thanks for the share. Reading this made me think of something else though, I might be able to hack what I need with hardhat tasks

Comment: @thatguyintech can you share the solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question; try something like this:

Use `hre.network.config.url`;

Here is an example of how you can get the RPC Provider URL at runtime in your `deploy.js` script:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

console.log("provider url: ", hre.network.config.url);
```

So then, for example if you run the deploy locally, the provider URL might be undefined:

```bash
% npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js
provider url:  undefined
```

But if you switch to a network that you have defined, you will then see the api provider URL:

```bash
% npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network rinkeby
provider url:  https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/<api-key>
```

Comment: thank you!! the answers from hexcowboy and @hellopeach helped a ton too but it was exactly the config.url attribute that I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to get in the updated part of the question, I think you can use `hre.network.name`, which is the name of the current network set in the config file that the `hre` is currently running with.

Basically, if you want to access the raw config values, use `hre.config`, if you want to know which network the hre is currently running with, use `hre.network.name`

Answer (score 2):

The `hre` contains the default RPC at **`hre.ethers.provider.connection.url`** which will return something like `http://localhost:8545`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my testcase:

const hardhatConfig = require("../hardhat.config");
console.log(hardhatConfig.networks.hardhat.forking.url)